# How to ask for an updated homebrew-formula for v8?

Tags: git, version, homebrew, v8

The version of V8 as deployed by homebrew is 5.1.281.47.
The actual version is 6.5.nn as stated at https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git.

I had no success trying compile a new version with the help of https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Building-with-GN (obviously my system is not set-up for bootstrapping/compiling software-packages)

Is there a correct way to ask the "community" for a homebrew update of v8?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm the `pinepain/devtools` tap author.

Feels free to use [pinepain/devtools](https://github.com/pinepain/homebrew-devtools) tap, I manage it and try to keep up to date. It has vanilla v8 versions. 6.5 should be there in a next few days. It should fit vast majority needs. Hope, you'll find it useful. If you will have any further question, feels free to open an issue there or ping me directly.

Comment: Worked like a a charm - perfekt. It's not exactly what I asked for, therefore no "accepted answer" tag. I did the following steps to install v8: 1. brew tap pinepain/devtools 2. brew install v8@6.5. The binaries are located here: /usr/local/opt/v8@6.5/lib

Comment: I forked Homebrew's v8 formula long time ago to bump version, so the only difference apart of newer version is that I do not publish `shell` (https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/samples/shell.cc) binary under `v8` name as `d8` shell is more convenient and has more features, so having `shell`, which is just an example, under `v8` name is a bit misleading imo.